# How do I persist an API access token from an external API between calls to my internal API

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

[Diagram of current solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoO1M.png)

I am setting up a .net Web Api 2 project to accomodate calls to an external service we are looking to use which performs parsing of certain data from emails. The Web Api 2 project will have an action for ad-hoc/individual requests and also an action which the windows scheduled task will call to bulk-process emails.

This external service requires us to pass login credentials and will return an access token which expires after some time.

How do I persist this token within my own web api so that every call to my internal API can reuse this token until the expiry, after which a new token will be retrieved? Or can the token only live as long as the current request?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dependency injection container, you can store the access token (for example as a private property) in your object (used by both API endpoints) registered as singleton - and verify expiry of the token before invoking your external service. You then either re-use the token, or generate new one.

Alternatively you can store the access token into a static property of the class. The token will be saved as long as your .NET app domain will not be destroyed.

In both cases you should think whether you are okay with thread-unsafe implementation of the access token retrieval (most of the cases), or you want to invest additional effort for thread-safe approach.